# Filter select boxes in AngularJS chosen in any order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, filter, combinations

I have 6 columns in my Database:

```
Date || Device Type (iPad, Android, etc.) || Client Type (HTML, iOS, etc.) 

App Version (1.3, 2.2, etc.) || Customer (Cust1, Cust2, etc.) || User (User 1, User2, etc.)
```

I want to build an AngularJS UI where I can filter this data to see the number of daily logins grouped by a certain column (Device, Client, Customer,etc.), and filtered by any of the other columns.

I should be able to add `<select>` boxes for each filter I want, and the options in each `<select>` should be determined by the filters above it.

For example, I might want to see the number of logins for every **device type** where **client type is iOS** and **customer is cust2**.

First, I select that I want to group by **device type**.

Second, I add a dropdown and choose to filter by **client type**, another dropdown appears next to it with all the valid **client types** obtained from the Database.

Next, I add another dropdown and choose to filter by **customer**, another dropdown appears next to it, with all the **customers** that have data for the  **client type** chosen above.

So, if I chose **iOS as client type**, then only **customers** that have data for **iOS** should show up in the next dropdown.

The part I'm stuck on is how to account for all the possible ways in which the filters may be chosen, because the options will be affected by the filters chosen before it. If I remember my combinatorics correctly, there are **4! ways** of choosing the filters.

Rather than having a LOT of nested conditionals, how can I achieve this view in AngularJS?

Thanks!

Comment: Right now I have checkboxes to choose which filters you want to apply, but those filter options aren't impacted by the order in which the checkboxes are selected. 

I don't really need help with coding this view, I need help with figuring out the algorithm for it.

Comment: Well, it's still hard to say anything without see any `code`.